# import fails in node 14.7 clientside javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, importerror

I want to split my javascript into packages but I also want to use express which is now an ES module.  I haven't been able to break my client side java script into modules when I have both ES and cjs modules.  Here is my latest attempt which I pulled off the web after my own code became too corrupted. This recent example doesn't work either.  my node is 14.7

```
//package.json
"name": "esmtest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node runner.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}

//hi.mjs
export function sayHi(name) {
    return "Hi, " + name + "!"
}

//hi-web.mjs
import express from "express";
import { sayHi } from "hi.mjs";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.json({ "message": sayHi("LogRocket") }));

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Hello ESM with @std/esm !!"));

//runner.js
require = require("@std/esm")(module);
module.exports = require("./hi-web.mjs").default;
''''
my latest error message:
S C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\esm test> npm start

> esmtest@1.0.0 start C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\esm test
> node runner.js

(node:4072) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\bubblegum\Desktop\esm test\runner.js:1
import { sayHi } from './hi.mjs'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1277:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1105:32)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

I've tried just about every combination of .js and .mjs, import and export, and upgrading node.  with the esm package I finally imported express but not all the modules.  It is usually the first import that doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out @std/esm no longer works.  instead use esm.  so
''''
require = require("esm")(module);
module.exports = require("./hi-web.mjs").default;

```
source: https://github.com/standard-things/esm
```